# print a variable in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, function, psql

I have a declaration as below

```
declare
qry text;
mycur cursor is select id from my table;
begin
    qry = "update mytable id = 101 where id = " || mycur.id;
    print qry; --something like this
    execute qry;
end;
```

I could use below command,

```
raise info 'value is %', qry
```

But, I want to print the qry variable (for verification) and then I need to execute it.

How can I do this?

Comment: `raise` **will** print the variable. What exactly is it that you don't like about it?

Comment: @horse, I need to execute which have raised in info mode.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. What exactly is it you want to print? Please edit your question and add the expected output.

Comment: @horse, just I need to store the raise information into one variable (as a query) and need print that (for verification), and then i need to executed it.